# Crystal Report error when trying to build a website with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am trying to run a build of a website locally on my pc using visual studio and while it builds fine, after I logon to my website which runs crystal reports I get the following error:

```
An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime.

Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly.

Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.
```

I have tried using VS 2008 and 2010. I have got the SAP build for both 08 and 10. I tried using 64 and 32 bit versions of each build. Nothing works and I keep getting this error. I am running this on a 64 bit Windows 7 if that helps. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, Marino3d. What do you mean by "the SAP build for both 08 and 10"? What runtime installer did you use on your server? What CrystalDecisions assemblies are installed on that server?

Answer (score 0):

be sure that you configure your project in x86.

Go to your application project, right click, and select "Properties"
On the Build tab, find the Platform Target combo box. It probably says, "Any CPU". Change this to x86 .